# Android Studio Build Timeout

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am receiving this message when compiling my code which was running fine just moments ago

```
    What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:[17.0.0].
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://10.252.250.53:8081/lm/content/groups/public/com/google/android/gms/play-services-iid/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'http://10.252.250.53:8081/lm/content/groups/public/com/google/android/gms/play-services-iid/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Read timed out
```

Comment: Did you update the IDE or anyother dependencies ?

Comment: no I just did clean rebuild.

Comment: what do you get in your Logcat ? Any types of errors ?

Comment: studio's build terminal shows above message after saying FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: look for java compiler errors in the build

Comment: There are none just this message comes after a minute into compilation. Seems like some network issue as more and more laptops in my team are facing this now can you check if the ip mentioned is accessible from your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were using some in built libraries in our application which were hosted on server which had some issues and all request to sync the applications thus resulted in timeout.

Answer (score 4):

Try this first.

1. `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.`

If that didn't work. Try the following.

2. `Close the android Studio, killall -9 java to ensure all java process has been terminated. And relaunch Android Studio.`

Answer (score 1):

(1) check your internet connection or try with other network might be there is an issue with downloading dependency.

(2) File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.

Comment: Cannot try with any other network. Cache restart did not work.

Comment: try with other network, i was facing similar issue from corporate internet(where few links are block and hence dependency not able to download).But after using my personal mobile hotspot internet it was working fine. (2) also make sure you have not setup proxy in your studio because i see IP address in you question instead of domain name (http://10.252.250.53:8081/lm/content/groups/public/com/google/android/gms/play-services-iid/maven-metadata.xml)